# Looping through A-Z and sorting array to JSON using MYSQL

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Arrays with JSON... my enemy.

I'm trying to get this to sort A-Z properly, I will explain. I have the following php code:

```
$az_result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY game_title");

while($az_row = mysqli_fetch_array($az_result))
{
    $the_az_game_data = array();

    $empty_letter = '';

    $current_letter = strtolower($az_row['game_title'][0]);
    if ($empty_letter != $current_letter) {
        $cur_letter = strtoupper($current_letter);
        $empty_letter = $current_letter;
    }

    $game_id = $az_row['ID'];

    $the_az_game_data['game_id'] = $game_id;
    $the_az_game_data['game_name'] = $az_row['game_title'];
    $the_az_game_data['game_link'] = $az_row['game_link'];


    //store data
    $az_data[$cur_letter] = $the_az_game_data;

}

$game_data[] = $az_data;


echo '{"games":'.json_encode($game_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT).'}';
```

The following is the JSON output:

```
{"games":[
    {
        "C": {
            "game_id": "17",
            "game_name": "Cool Game",
            "game_link": "cool-game",
        },
        "R": {
            "game_id": "2",
            "game_name": "Rad Game 2",
            "game_link": "rad-game-2",
        },
        "T": {
            "game_id": "1",
            "game_name": "Test Game",
            "game_link": "test-game",
        }
    }
]}
```

So I ALMOST have it, but what's wrong is that there are actually multiple games in those letters. It is overriding arrays or something? Can someone explain, thanks!

Comment: Dynamically append another array element: `$az_data[$cur_letter][] = $the_az_game_data;`

Comment: I swear I tried this, thanks it worked... lol

Comment: AND: `echo json_encode(array('games'=>$game_data), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`